# Autolayout for button to bottom

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, constraints, uistoryboard

I try to adapt my app for the 3.5 inches iPhone, but currently I have a problem, because I don't really get how to use the constraints to get what I want.

This is what I have for 4 inches:

[image: 4 inches iPhone]

This is what happens, if I apply 3.5 inches Form Factor:

[image: 3.5 inches iPhone]

But this is what I would like to have, managed by constraints:
[image: 3.5 inches iPhone correct]

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Do learn autolayout. Hit and Trial won't help you..

Answer (score 1):

I Think you need add constraint on all three objects 
Do following steps

1). First add three constraint to top image view
I am attaching the image for that
In this image you need to give value according to your requirement
as i understand from above image i am giving the 20 from top and 0 from left and 0 from right
then click on the Add constraint button as you see in bottom of the image

[image: Constraint image]

2). then add constraint on take a note button in the same way that you have added from first

3). add constraint on last button

Comment: I tried this approach, but I couldn't see any difference.

Comment: please take a reference either top of or bottom layout then add constraint according to that reference.you will able to to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Add this constraint to your button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply **autolayout** **constraints** on both **note and save button** along with **imageView** so when u open your app in 3.5 or 4 inches it will adjust and fit your component as per your size. You could also go for **RESET TO SUGGESTED CONSTRAINTS** if you are not able to understand on how to apply and for more on autolayout you could [check out this tut](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)